# how to get Remote Desktop client to show all the colors of web app images?

Tags: windows, colors, remote-desktop

I built a web app, I have a table with border color #888 and header background color #eee.

I also have a pretty gradient background image.

Looks great on my Windows XP machine.  According to Desktop > Properties > Settings, "Color Quality" is "Highest (32 bit)".

I have to demo my app from the boardroom using a Remote Desktop client running on Windows 7.  When I do, I set the remote desktop client settings to "Highest 32-bit" as well.

But my web app looks crappy -- the #eee background color looks white, and the gradient background image has thick lines of progressively darker color rather that a nice smooth gradient.

Any ideas about how I can get my web app to look right through Remote Desktop client?

Comment: Is your question 'how can I make my web app work better through Remote Desktop' or 'how can I make Remote Desktop display my web app correctly'?  If the latter, you may have better luck asking it on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Bringing in a laptop may be a better solution.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks, but not an option.  It's secure environment, the only way I can see the web app is to remote desktop to my dev machine.

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/208379/32-bit-colour-in-rdp-still-has-colour-banding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The color depth of a RD session depends on settings on both the client and the server. In this case, it sounds like you have the client settings correct, but you may need to configure the Windows XP machine with Group Policy, as described in [this MSKB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278502).